# How to broadcast message to multiple client groups in hub class

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Currently I am trying to broadcast messages in my hub class to a list of groups, `List<string> groups`.  How would I go about broadcasting these messages to each of these groups, I don't know if this is the best way to do it using a `foreach` or `for` loop

```
foreach(string group in groups){
   Clients[group].sendMessage(message);
}
```

if you had a lot of groups i take it this wouldn't be the most efficient way, each group only has 1 user in it as i amusing their username as their group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a foreach loop is the only way you can achieve what you want, at least in SignalR v0.5.2. Maybe a future version includes a way to broadcast to multiple groups in one call, but I wouldn't be too worried about the loop (remember everything in SignalR is async, so broadcasting is too).